# Aluminum Anti-Seize - Suctioned Bottle

Tags: anti-seize, aluminum

The aluminum anti-seize (Permatex) that I have had for several years has suctioned the bottle (Sides bending in a lot). I haven't used it for over a year so I don't know when or how fast this happened.

Does anyone know why this happens and if the anti-seize is still good?

**UPDATE:** Reached out to Permatex and got the following response. They didn't know what caused the shrinkage, but did state that it has a *"3 year shelf life"* and that *"If the product is still has good consistency then it is okay to use, if it has stiffened up, try adding a little mineral oil to it."* I am going to continue to use what I have since mine still seems to have the same consistency.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no chemist, but the [safety data sheet](https://www.permatex.com/wp-content/uploads/tech_docs/sds/01_USA-English/80078.pdf) suggests the presence of 10-30 % calcium oxide by weight.

Calcium oxide [appears to be hygroscopic](http://cameo.mfa.org/wiki/Calcium_oxide), so just like old brake fluid in a bottle it absorbs moisture from the air present inside the container and creates a small suction effect.

I can't comment on the efficacy of old anti-seize, but it will likely depend on the role that the calcium oxide plays.